# Default checked for apex:selectOption in Visual force page

Tags: visualforce, apex

In HTML we do have option to make a radio button checked by default. Same shown with HTML code snippet below.

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
</form>
```

Do we have similar option available in visual force page as well? If yes how we can achieve it? 
Does it require to write a JavaScript code or can achieve through controller?
Please suggest, if solution in code provided will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution and same providing below.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex: page controller="SampleCustomController">
<apex:selectRadio value="{!defaultCheck}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="Male" name="Male"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="Female" name="Female"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
</apex:page>
```

Apex controller class:

```
public class SampleCustomController{
public String defaultCheck{get;set;}

SampleCustomController(){

if(defaultCheck==NULL)
{   defaultCheck='Male';}

}
}
```